# Dúvida Gem Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Olá,

Estou usando a gem devise para um projeto próprio e surgiu uma dúvida, como faço para deixar apenas uma rota livre, por exemplo quero que todas as outras rotas precisem de login e senha menos a página principal.

Fiz algumas pesquisas e cheguei neste [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-resource-actions-that-require-authentication-using-routes.rb) mas não deu certo.

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal usar desta forma?

Considerando que você deseja permitir acesso sem autenticação apenas para a página principal da aplicação:

> application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  # Insira esta linha
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

> home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  # Insira esta linha
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
  end
end
```

Desta forma, será requisitada a autenticação do usuário em todos os controllers e suas actions, **exceto** ao controller responsável pela página principal da sua aplicação.

E se por algum motivo você quiser se limitar apenas a action "index" do controller responsável pela página principal da sua aplicação, você pode fazer desta forma:

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index]
```

Espero ter compreendido o seu problema e ter te ajudado a solucioná-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal fazer algo assim ...

Como você deseja permitir o acesso não autenticado somente à página principal do aplicativo:

É assim que eu gosto de configurar meu aplicativo

1) no arquivo de rotas

```
  # config / routes.rb
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    ide_for: users,: controllers => {registrações: 'users / registrations',
                                         sessões: 'usuários / sessões',
                                         senhas: 'usuários / senhas',
                                         confirmações: 'usuários / confirmações'
    }
    autenticar: o usuário faz
      namespace: os usuários fazem
        recursos: posts
        root: to => 'channels # index'
      fim
    fim
    recursos: contats
    match "/ about_us" => "pages # about_us",: as =>: about_us, via:: todos
    Páginas de raiz # índice '
  fim
```

desta forma, todas as rotas que estão fora do ** namespace ** usuários são públicas

Eu também crie um controlador de usuário mestre que o controlador de aplicativos estendido assim

```
# app / controllers / user_controller.rb
classe UserController <ApplicationController
  before_filter: authenticate_user!
fim
```

agora para todos os controladores de dispositivos

```
# app / controllers / users / registrations_controller.rb
Usuários da classe :: RegistrationsController <Devise :: RegistrationsController
  privado
  def after_sign_in_path_for (usuário)
    user_root_path
  fim
fim
```

Todo o controlador dos meus usuários estende o meu controlador de usuário

```
# app / controllers / users / posts_controller.rb
classe Usuários :: PostsController <UserController
  ...
fim
```

Você pode seguir este formato para todos os outros controladores. Se você ainda precisar de ajuda, avise-me.